# Need an example of using GetAddrInfoEx with timeout

Tags: c++, winapi

It was necessary to use `GetAddrInfo`, but it does not have a timeout implementation. So I liked `GetAddrInfoEx`, which has this feature. I looked on the Internet, I did not find the use with a timeout. There is a sample code that I started. However, the execution result is incorrect.

```
ADDRINFOEX* resultEx = NULL;
 DWORD dwNamespace = NS_ALL;
 LPGUID lpNspid = NULL;

 struct timeval timeout{};
 timeout.tv_sec = 5000;
 timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    wstring host_str = string_to_wstring("time.nist.gov");
    const wchar_t* hostName = host_str.c_str();

    wstring sevice_str = string_to_wstring("ntp");
    const wchar_t* serviceName = sevice_str.c_str();

    int ret2 = GetAddrInfoEx(hostName, serviceName, dwNamespace, lpNspid, NULL, &resultEx, &timeout, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

`GetAddrInfoEx` returns 0 if successful.

It currently returns error 10022.
*WSAEINVAL 10022 - Invalid argument. Some invalid argument was supplied (for example, specifying an invalid level to the setsockopt function). In some instances, it also refers to the current state of the socket—for instance, calling accept on a socket that is not listening.*
[Windows Sockets Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2)

If we remove the timeout and use Empty, then it returns 0

Comment: *"However, the execution result is incorrect."* - Please describe the expected behavior and the observed behavior. Make sure to read [ask] as well.

Comment: Google for some reason really wants to give you results for `GetAddrInfo` when you search for `GetAddrInfoEx`, but it does offer you a link to give you results for what you actually want. Just follow that link. I did that and found [something useful on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/DNSAsyncNetworkNameResolution/cpp/ResolveName.cpp).

Comment: Also if you search for `getaddrinfoex sample` instead for `example` then Google does the right thing. Google is weird.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you following the [documented contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfoexa), specifically: *"This parameter is only supported when the `UNICODE` or `_UNICODE` macro has been defined in the sources before calling the `GetAddrInfoEx` function. Otherwise, this parameter is currently reserved and must be set to `NULL` since a **timeout** option is not supported."*

Comment: @IInspectable the code is clearly using the Unicode function as Unicode strings are being passed to it

Comment: The `timeout.tv_sec` field is expressed in **seconds**, not **milliseconds**. Setting it to 5000 is asking for over an hour, not 5 seconds, are you sure that is what you really want?

Comment: `timeout.tv_sec = 5;`
setting the parameter does not change the error code

Comment: An invalid parameter was provided. This error is returned if any of the reserved parameters are not NULL. `timeout` is only supported when the UNICODE or _UNICODE macro has been defined in the sources before calling the GetAddrInfoEx function. Otherwise, this parameter is currently reserved and must be set to NULL since a timeout option is not supported. Whether you have defined UNICODE or _UNICODE macro? `#define UNICODE`or`#define _UNICODE`